# restrict access to images on server : php, htaccess or other?

Tags: php, image, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am building an image server to process and deliver company images.  My goal is to build a system that can receive images (from ftp or an app), resize / watermark them, and make them available for social media or internal use (with nice short urls.)

The problem I am having involves restricting access.  each image is assigned an 8 digit code.  The htaccess file is designed to return the correct image so that :

mysite.com/84375635   becomes  mysite.com/images/84375635.png

This allows anyone to access any image.  I want to set up a system that will restrict specific images, based on requirements stored in a database or a file.  I'v thought of the possible solutions:

- use php to rewrite the htaccess file when an image is uploaded.
- use php to receive image requests, then redirect according to the restrictions in the database.

Which is the better choice (or is there one I don't know of yet?)

I want this element of the system to be as quick and low-memory as possible.

Comment: posts like this are in danger of being closed due to lack of specificity. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definetly use PHP to process image requests, and query the database in that script.

Never rewrite `.htaccess` files with PHP per request. That probably wouldn't even work, the access rules will be parsed before the PHP script is executed, not after.

If the database server is running on localhost then the overhead this script causes will be negligible, regarding time and memory consumption.

---

If the restrictions are purely based on IP ranges that are allowed to access the files, and those which are not, then you can also rewrite the access rules upon image upload.
Note that this also depends on the number of images you are planning to have uploaded: If it's just a few it's not a problem - but having hundred thousands of rules in an `.htaccess` file is certainly something you shouldn't do (a PHP based image serving script in combination with a database is not only faster but also safer then).

Although this solution requires slightly less resources, it's also less extensible (e.g. when you want to add more restrictions than just IPs one day). Keep in mind to also delete entries when you delete images.

Comment: I agree, Editing the htaccess file during an image request is pointless.  At that point, I might as well just redirect.  Actually, I was considering using php to edit the htaccess file when the image was uploaded.  That way, the system would not need to query the database each time an image was requested

Comment: In your post you write that you upload images through an app **or** via FTP. The latter won't trigger any PHP script to be executed, so unless you want to do that manually (or periodically with a cron job..) changing the ruleset on image upload is not an option in your scenario. Additionally, you might not be able to transfer all access rules directly to `.htaccess` files (depending on the nature of the restrictions, e.g. user based).

Comment: Yes, if uploaded via php, the user will still have to visit a webpage in order to enter image info (name, description, etc.)  at this point, if they flag the image as internal, all requests for that image from the internet at large should fail.  That is the only restriction.  (Note: within the app, the uploading and data entry is all done in one step.)

Comment: Thanks! This is a big help.  There will be 1000+ images

Answer (score 1):

You really should NOT rewrite your htaccess files with PHP - this will blow up in your face at some point.

> mysite.com/84375635 becomes mysite.com/images/84375635.png

Why not just use the DirectoryIndex to select the file - set up a unique directory for each image, then add the following in your config:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php index.png
```

Then you can simply drop in your file as 'index.png', and if you later want to add more sophisticated access controls, rename the image as .htimg.png and drop in an index.php to mediate the access to the file.

The disadvantage with this approach is that you need to allow PHP execution within the same directory tree as file uploads - which is bad for security, hence a better solution would be to rename the image file as '.htimg.png' then mediate the access via the 404 handler.

You currently allow file uploads by FTP - this poses problems for ensuring consistent naming practices (and FTP is a major PITA to maintain, automate and secure). I'd recommend ditching this.

Comment: That's kind of misusing the [DirectoryIndex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html) directive, which is meant to provide HTML output (from not only .html files as source). Using a `RewriteRule` to redirect these kinds of requests is common pratice and should not be replaced by creating directories for each single image. Additionally this doesn't really answer the question, as that is about restricting access to particular files - not about the redirection.

Comment: Why is it "misusing" the DirectoryIndex directive? It's explicitly doing what DirectoryIndex is supposed to do: "List of resources to look for when the client requests a directory". And redirection implies maintaining the file in a location directly accessible by the webserver - which means it's impossible to *restrict* access.